# Cannot browse internet with 48Gb of Ram

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, virtual-memory

I have 48Gb of Highspeed Ram and yet I cannot download from Steam or a site like MyAirBridge without my computer slowing to an absolute crawl. Even moving the mouse around the screen I have stuttering or playing music it breaks up.

According to the Task Manager windows 10 is only using 9.9/47.9 GB of the Ram

I have found that if I manually change the Page file size to something like 7030 Min 18000 Max
that the computer runs perfectly fine no matter what I am doing even with a million browsers open and downloading from Steam.

But then as soon as I restart my computer Windows automatically changes the Paging file size back to 3,000  and my computer is running like crap again.

First of all it should not even be close to needing to use any Virtual memory at all but it does and it sets the virtual memory way too low for what it apparently needs.

Is there any good solution to this problem short of having to manually change my Page file size back every time I restart my computer since windows wants to muck everything up?

Any Help is appreciated.

Psi

[System Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNm4x.jpg)

Comment: Are you aware that having 48 GB does not make a difference in your Steam download speeds?  You should be allowing your system to manage the size of your page file.  If the page file is reverting back to 3 GB there is something else going on (unclear what).  All I know is my system with 64 GB the page file is only 9 GB (although that increases with increase workloads).  I recently closed my Edge session with 300 tabs.

Comment: Only data pages (ie memory pages that change) go into the swap file. Executables, DLLs, font files the actual exe disk file (etc) is the swap file for code pages.  So there's a downside.